# FSM to actual java code. Not sure if code is correct

Tags: java, network-programming, state-machine

This is for school, but not homework. I'm trying to understand how RDT is implemented and i was able to find another school that had a simulator already created, but just have to fill in the sender and receiver. Anyway, I can't get it work properly. There is some Pseudo code and an FSM diagram for both the sender and receiver. I believe the sender is correct, but I'm not too sure about the receiver. I've never dealt with finite state machine diagrams before, so I'm still trying to figure that out too.

I'll list the receiver to make sure that's right and post more code if need be.

[image: FMS receiver]

## Global Variables:

```
  astate =0 // can be 0-3, corresponds to state diagram for a/sender (3.15)
  astored_pkt // saved in case we need to retransmit - for a/sender
  bstate = 0 // can be 0-1,state diagram for b (3.14)
  bOnceThru = 0 // A flag to track if this is the first time through the receiver
  bstored_pkt // saved in case we need to retransmit - for b/sender
```

## Pseudo Code:

```
bInput
    if pkt is corrupt
        if bOnceThru==1
            send bstored_pkt
        else
            do nothing
    else
        if (seqno==0 && bstate==0) || (seqno==1 && bstate==1)
            deliver data to layer 5
            Print "B: got packet #"
            create bstored_pkt
            sendpkt(bstored_pkt)
            Print "B: sending ACK #"
            incr bstate mod 2
            bOnceThru=1
        else
            if bstate==1 || bOnceThru==1
                send bstored_pkt
                Print "B: sending ACK #"
```

## Java Code:

```
protected void bInput(Packet packet){
    if(!isPktCorrupt(packet)){
        if(bOnceThru == 1){
            toLayer3(1,bstored_pkt);
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }else{
        if((packet.getSeqnum() == 0 && bstate == 0) ||
            (packet.getSeqnum() == 1 && bstate == 1)){
                toLayer5(packet.getPayload());
                System.out.println("B: got packet #");
                bstored_pkt = new Packet(packet);
                toLayer3(1,bstored_pkt);
                System.out.println("B: send ACK " + packet.getAcknum());
                bstate = (bstate + 1) % 2;
                if(packet.getSeqnum() == 0) bOnceThru = 1;
            }else{
                if(bstate == 1 || bOnceThru == 1){
                    toLayer3(1,bstored_pkt);
                    System.out.println("B: sending ACK " + packet.getAcknum());
                }
            }
    }

}
```

toLayer3 and toLayer5 are methods implemented already, nothing i need to worry about. Also, isPktCorrupt is a method to verify the check sum of the current packet with what it has stored.

Does this seem correct? Is the pseudo code even correct? It runs ok for the first packet and then the second packet just keeps trying to resend. I can't see why though. If i need to, i'll post the Sender as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is correct. I did find some errors in my sender (minor), but it threw it completely off. I had to change one thing in the receiver code though, and that was the increment of bstate. So, in case anyone is wondering or has a similar question, this code does correlate to the FSM and it does work.